# JSF select menu problem

Tags: jsf

I am developing a jsf,richfaces application.where i want to populate the values of second select menu on the basis of selecting the choice from the first one  .How i can achieve this.

```
  <h:outputText id="section1" value="Section" />
    <h:selectOneMenu  id="section2" value="#{content.sectionName}" >
        <f:selectItems value="#{content.sections}" />
  </h:selectOneMenu>
```

what exactly i want is:
I have two tables one for category and one for section.
If a user choose a category from drop down menu then the other drop down menu for section should have the values only for selected category.

Please he

Answer (score 2):

As per your question history you're using Ajax4jsf/RichFaces. Better use `<a4j:support>` instead of `valueChangeListener`.

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="section2" value="#{content.sectionName}" >
    <f:selectItems value="#{content.sections}" />
    <a4j:support event="onchange" action="#{content.changeSection}" reRender="otherMenuId" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

In the `changeSection()` method you need to populate the select items for the 2nd menu. The `otherMenuId` must refer to `id` of the other `<h:selectOneMenu>` in the same `<a4j:region>`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a `valueChangeListener` for your first `selectOneMenu`:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="select1" valueChangeListener="#{myBean.updateSections}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{myBean.sections1}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Inside `MyBean#updateSections` you have to modify the list of SelectItems the second selectOneMenu has to show according to the selection you made.

Furthermore you have to submit your form or rerender section2 to display the updated values in section2.